# LMX2820 readback operation

Tags: spi, texas-instruments, pll, synthesizer

How can a readback operation be done on [LMX2820](https://www.ti.com/product/LMX2820)?

I've looked through over it's [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lmx2820), register map and AN documents and there is no information about that. In [LMX2594](https://www.ti.com/product/LMX2594) read and write operations are controlled with MSB, but I've tried it on LMX2820 and MUXOUT pin is silent.

Comment: what do you mean by `readback`?

Comment: Reading registers from pll using SPI. MISO is MUXOUT pin

Comment: Are you pulling CE high?

Comment: Yes, xd. I am able to program it, set needed frequency and so on, but cannot read from it.